# It is capturing SQL command text supported in .net 4.6 application in Application Insights?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

Imagine .NET 4.6 console app, that using ADO.NET to query sql database.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "my key";

        var tc = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active);

        tc.TrackEvent("App start");

        string ConnString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        string SqlString = "Select * From Customers";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var res = reader.Read();
                }
            }
        }


        tc.TrackEvent("App stop");
        tc.Flush();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

It is capturing SQL command text in this case supported? Or it is supported only on IIS and Azure App?

In this sample I would like to see text "Select * From Customers" on Application Insights in dependency event, but this text is not there. There is only dependency with few other properties like duration, client IP, etc., but not sql text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sql statements are collected by "status monitor", which is running as a .net profiler at runtime, on web apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-dependencies

I'll ask around, but i'm *pretty sure* it isn't easy to hook that up on non-web apps without jumping through a *lot* of hoops.

Comment: after talking to @dmitry-matveev it is *theoretically* possible, but that theory probably isn't worth actually trying.  it would require a lot of things that you're probably better off just recording yourself manually using custom events or custom properties, unless you have a very large and complicated console app you're trying to instrument.

Comment: thank you. As you are saying, I will record desired information manually.